# How to validate more than one email in kendo ui

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I gave like

```
<td> <label for="email" class="required">To:</label></td>
       <td><input type="email" id="email" name="Email" class="k-textbox" placeholder="e.g. myname@example.net"  required data-email-msg="Email format is not valid"  "/></td>
```

and in the

```
document.ready(function(){}
```

I have defined like

```
var validator = $("#email").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

It is validating single email, I want to validate more than one email at a time. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand : you have only one `input` field for an e-mail? Can you enter multiple e-mails in this `input` field? Or do you try to have many input with the same id (here it is `email`) : in this case, you have to use something else than an id (which should be unique by definition).

Comment: i will enter multiple e-mails in this field,I have to validate all e-mails entered in the input field

Answer (score 0):

You should then add the attribute `multiple` to the input tag:

```
<input type="email" 
       id="email" 
       name="Email" 
       class="k-textbox" 
       placeholder="e.g. myname@example.net" 
       required 
       data-email-msg="Email format is not valid" 
       multiple="multiple"/>
```

You can now add multiple email adresses separated by a coma.

Comment: I have implemented this,If I enter multiple e-mail addresses by a coma then also it is not properly validating,For first e-mailaddress it is validating and if i enter second email address correctly also it is saying "Email format is not valid"

Comment: It is an HTML5 tag so it works in all browser except IE... Thus, the easiest way is to create your own pattern : `<input type='text' pattern='\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*' />` (note the type which is text and no longer email in order to use the custom pattern).